# With Kernel 3.5.0-21 the wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT stop working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, kernel, realtek, lan

Yesterday, I updated my Ubuntu 12.04 to the Kernel 3.5.0-21 and the wireless card stop working... In other threads I saw the same problem with another kernels.
Anyone have the new driver?
I sent a mail to Realtek but I have not received an answer yet...

The model is: Realtek RTL8723AE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you installed the driver by downloading and compiling the Realtek package. When a new kernel is installed by Update Manager, you must recompile:

```
cd Desktop/RT8723  <--or wherever you compiled the package
sudo su
make clean
make
make install
modprobe rtl8723e
exit
```

Oops! It errors for me, too. You might try this package: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2012/12/04/compat-drivers-2012-12-04.tar.gz

```
./scripts/driver select rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8723ae
```

You 'make clean' because the module was compiled originally against your specific versions of kernel, headers, gcc, etc. When updates are installed, the various files built in the compile process may or may not work correctly with, for instance, a newer gcc version, so wipe it all out and start fresh: make clean.

Comment: Hi, I tried to recompile the package, but it doesn't work anymore. I think that I need another driver, for 3.5.0-21 version. Before the update I had 3.5.0-19... Why do you do "make clean" before recompile? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but It didn't work :( I tried installing the driver in the others kernels (I have 3.5.0-17, 19 and 21) and nothing... any ideas?

Comment: Let's see: lspci -nn | grep 0280. We wonder if the driver covers your device. Is your device 10ec:8723?

Comment: The command gave me this:

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8723]

Comment: When you sudo modprobe rtl8723e, are there any errors or warnings? Any clues in dmesg | grep rtl? Is the wireless switch on or off: rfkill list all? Is a wireless interface wlan0 created: iwconfig?

Comment: Hi, with modprobe it's all fine, no errors. *dmseg* `firemare: rtl8723fw_B.bin / ieee80211 phy0: >Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc' / rtlwifi: wireless switch is on` *rfkill list all* `0: hci0: bluetooth soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no / 1: phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no` *iwconfig* `wlan0 IEEE 802 ESSID:off/any / Mode: Managed Acces Point: Not-Associated... / lo no wireless extensions. / eth0 no wireless extensions.` I hope that helps... Thanks again :)

Comment: Looking good so far. You have a wireless interface wlan0. Does it scan? sudo iwlist wlan0 scan. If it scans, then you should be able to click the Network Manager icon, see your network and connect.

Comment: wlan0     No scan results :(

Comment: Please check dmesg to see if there is a firmware problem: dmesg | grep -i rtl. If so, get and install the firmware as here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12426756&postcount=21